# Dúvida com Regex

Tags: javascript, string, regex

Boa noite.

Eu preciso de uma expressão regular que possar capturar os números/expressões antes e depois de um determinado caractere, como este `^`.

Por exemplo, na string abaixo eu preciso que ela me retorne `(5 * 77 + 4)^6` e `7^3`:

```
5! + 8 - 5(ln(3)) + (5 * 77 + 4)^6 - 7^3
```

A expressões que criei até o momento foram estas:

- `/((\()?(.)+(\))?)+(\^)+((\()?(.)+(\))?)/g`
- `/\(*\w+\)*(\^)+\(*\w+\)*/g`

É importante que ele verifique se há apenas um `^`.

[**Nesse exemplo**](https://regex101.com/r/uL2fQ0/3) há uma aplicação funcional do segundo caso em uma string, contudo não estou conseguindo aplicar isso no javascript.

Comment: Tenta ai: [^\^] Esta expressão usa a lista negada.

Comment: @DenerCarvalho, nesse caso ele não irá apenas capturar a string excluindo os `^`?

Comment: Sim, agora eu entendi o que vc quer, a minha expressão nao vai funcionar.

Comment: Vc quer isolar somente a operação matemática que usa a potencia `^`.

Comment: Isso mesmo. [Nesse link](https://regex101.com/r/uL2fQ0/3) há um exemplo que nesse site funciona, mas quando insiro no javascript, ele não me retorna o valor correto.

Comment: e porque a expressão não consegue reconhecer as operações  que estão entre parentes, tando a direita da potencia `^` quanto para a esquerda, somente uma operaçao sozinha 98^22.

Comment: Ele não traz os valores corretos porque está faltando grupos, veja esse exemplo: https://regex101.com/r/uL2fQ0/5 Porém ainda não consegui também fazer ele pegar outras expressões. Estou tentando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bem, o que queria com a captura desses números/expressões era simular a ação da função exponencial com o sinal `^`.

Obtive uma maneira de fazer isso, porém não foi somente com `regex`.

Primeiramente, tive que capturar tudo que havia antes do `^` de modo que sintaticamente isso se encaixasse na função exponencial. Por exemplo:

Na *string* abaixo, eu capturaria o `(2 - 9)`, ignorando os espaços em branco, independente de sua quantidade:

```
log(10) + (2 - 9) ^ 5
```

E depois teria que fazer o mesmo com o que havia após o `^`, o que ainda no exemplo acima seria o `5`.

Após isso eu deveria que aplicar essas capturas na função do javascript `Math, pow()` que executa a exponenciação, de acordo com o que já foi dito, ficaria:

```
Math.pow((2 - 9), 5)
```

E para finalizar, eu deveria repetir esse processo de captura>captura>concatenação até que não restasse mais nenhum `^` em meio a *string*. Pois assim eu poderia ter uma exponenciação dentro de outra exponenciação:

```
(2 ^ 3)^7
```

**o Javascript**

Para captura do que havia antes do `^`, o código foi esse:

```
function captureBefore(string) {
  var result;
  var n = string.indexOf("^");
  var i = n - 1;
  while (!(string.charAt(i) != " ")) {
    --i;
  }
  if (!(/\d/.test(string.charAt(i)))) {
    var nOpen = 1;
    var nClose = 0;
    while (nOpen != nClose) {
      if (string.charAt(i - 1) == ")") {
        ++nOpen;
      } else if (string.charAt(i - 1) == "(") {
        ++nClose;
      }
      i -= 1;
    }
    if (/[a-z]/.test(string.charAt(i - 1))) {
      while ((/[a-zA-Z.]/.test(string.charAt(i - 1)))) {
        i -= 1;
      }
    }
    result = string.substring(i, n);
  } else {
    while (/\d/.test(string.charAt(i)) || /[-|+|.]/.test(string.charAt(i))) {
      i -= 1;
    }
    result = string.substring(i + 1, n);
  }
  return result;
}
```

E para o que havia depois:

```
function captureAfter(string) {
  var result;
  var n = string.indexOf("^");
  var i = n + 1;
  while (string.charAt(i) == " " || /[a-zA-Z.]/.test(string.charAt(i))) {
    ++i;
  }
  if (/[-|+]/.test(string.charAt(i))) {
    ++i;
  }
  if (!(/(\d)/.test(string.charAt(i)))) {
    var nOpen = 1;
    var nClose = 0;
    while (nOpen != nClose) {
      if (string.charAt(i + 1) == "(") {
        ++nOpen;
      } else if (string.charAt(i + 1) == ")") {
        ++nClose;
      }
      i += 1;
    }
    result = (string.substring(n + 1, i + 1));
  } else {
    while (/\d/.test(string.charAt(i)) || /[-|+|.]/.test(string.charAt(i))) {
      i += 1;
    }
    result = (string.substring(n + 1, i));
  }
  return result;
}
```

E para que se repetisse e a função alcançasse todos os sinais:

```
if (/\^/g.test(string)) {
  string = string.replace(/\s*\^\s*/g, "^")
  while (/\^/g.test(string)) {
    string = string.replace(captureBefore(string) + "^" + captureAfter(string), "Math.pow(" + captureBefore(string) + ", " + captureAfter(string) + ")");
  }
}
```

Com isso pude executar a função com sucesso. Mas caso alguém tenha uma ideia que tenha o mesmo resultado com menos código, ainda estou aberto a possibilidades.

[**Exemplo funcional**](https://jsfiddle.net/SamirChaves/586rnn3j/)